# Possible Xcode Validate Settings Bug

Tags: ios, xcode

I wrote an app originally for iOS 6, and I have since updated it to work on iOS 7. Now I want to build it to support the 64 bit iPhone 5s as well. In my project I switched the Architectures Build Setting to `Standard architectures (including 64-bit) (armv7, armv7s, arm64)`. Upon build Xcode prompted me to validate my settings, and told me to let it automatically choose the architecture. I let it do this, however it switched it back to the default, `Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s)`.

I looked for an answer on google but found no clear explanation.

I decided to ignore Xcode's warning, and fixed my app to support 64-bit and it built successfully (leaving the setting on `Standard architectures (including 64-bit)`)

However I hated the feeling of going against Xcode's advice, so I created a new project as a test. I found that the default architecture build setting of a new project was `Standard architectures (including 64-bit)`. I then clicked validate settings and found that even in this brand new project with nothing else changed, Xcode still wanted to change the architectures back to regular `Standard architectures`.

Is there a reason why Xcode is changing the architectures back, or is this a bug in the validate settings?

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Xcode.Actually it should set the architecture based on the active architecture available

Comment: @Anil Does this mean that I should ignore the warning and that there is nothing wrong with my app?